# How do I find the last number in a string with excel formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I'm parsing strings in excel, and I need to return everything through the last number. For example:

```
Input: A00XX
Output: A00
```

In my case, I know the last number will be between index 3 and 5, so I'm brute-forcing it with:

```
=LEFT([@Point],
IF(SUM((MID([@Point],5,1)={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"})+0),5,
    IF(SUM((MID([@Point],4,1)={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"})+0),4,
        IF(SUM((MID([@Point],3,1)={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"})+0),3,
))))
```

Unfortunately, I've run into some edge cases where the numbers extended beyond index 5. Is there a generic way to find the last number in a string using excel formulas?

Note:
I've tried `=MAX(SEARCH(...` but it returns the index of the first number, not the last.

Comment: Why not use VBA methods?

Comment: @CoolMind, This spreadsheet will be available to other (older) people. They've had issues using macro-enabled workbooks in the past. Making this a vba function is trivial, but I was hoping to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point: if we know the position of the last number, we can use `LEFT` to get the string to that point.  Suppose that the position is 5:

```
=LEFT(A1, 5)
```

But, we don't know the position of the last number.  Now, what if the only valid number was 0, and it only appeared once: then we could use `FIND` to locate the position of the number:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(0, A1))
```

But, we have more than one valid number.  Suppose that we had all the numbers from 0 through 9, but *each* number could only appear once — then we could use `MAX` on a `FIND` array, to tell us which of the numbers is the last one:

```
=LEFT(A1, MAX(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A1)))
```

Unfortunately, `FIND` will throw a `#VALUE!` error any number doesn't appear, which will then make `MAX` return the same error.  So, we need to fix *that* with `IFERROR`:

```
=LEFT(A1, MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A1), 0)))
```

However, numbers can appear more than once.  As such, we need a method to find the **last** occurrence of a value in a string (since `FIND` and `SEARCH` will, by default, return the *first* occurrence).

[The `SUBSTITUTE` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) has 3 mandatory arguments — Initial String, Value to be Replaced, Value to Replace with — and one Optional argument — *the occurrence to replace*.  Normally, this is omitted, so that *all* occurrences are replaced.  But, if we know *how many* times a character appears in a string, then we can replace *just* the **last** instance with a special/uncommon sub-string to search for.

To count how many times a character appears in a String, just start with the length of the String, then subtract the length when you `SUBSTITUTE` all copies of that character for Nothing:

```
=LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 0, ""))
```

This means we can now replace the **last** occurrence of the character with, for example, `">¦<"`, and then `FIND` *that*:

```
=FIND(">¦<", SUBSTITUTE(A1, 0, ">¦<", LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 0, ""))))
```

Of course, we want to do this for all the numbers from 0 to 9, and take the `MAX` value (remembering our `IFERROR`), so we need to put the Array of values back in:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(">¦<", SUBSTITUTE(A1, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, ">¦<", LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, "")))), 0))
```

Then, we plug that all back into our initial `LEFT` function:

```
=LEFT(A1, MAX(IFERROR(FIND(">¦<", SUBSTITUTE(A1, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, ">¦<", LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, "")))), 0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, assuming that the length of the string in question will never be more than 9 characters (which seems a safe assumption based on your description):

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(0,0+ISERR(0+MID(A1,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},1))))
```

This, depending on your version of Excel, may or may not require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Note also that the separator within the array constant `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}` is the semicolon, which, for English-language versions of Excel, represents the row-separator. This may require amending if you are using a non-English-language version.

Of course, we can replace this static constant with a dynamic construction. However, since we are already making the assumption that 9 is an upper limit on the number of characters for the string in question, this would not seem to be necessary.

Comment: I love this! So simple. I'm using Excel 365, so I used Sequence instead of manually creating the array: `=LEFT(A3,MATCH(0,0+ISERR(0+MID(A3,SEQUENCE(LEN(A3)),1))))`

Comment: Although it doesn't matter for my purposes, your formula doesn't work for discontiguous numbers. For example A00X0X returns A00 not A00X0.

Comment: I ended up using `SEQUENCE`  to allow arbitrary length, `XMATCH` to find the last number, and `LET` to simplify. I really do love Excel 365. Here's what I used: `=LET(s, A3, IFERROR(LEFT(s, XMATCH(0, --ISERR(--MID(s, SEQUENCE(LEN(s)), 1)), 0, -1)),""))`

Answer (score 3):

If you have the newest version of Excel, you can try something like:

```
=LEFT(D1,
LET(x, SEQUENCE(LEN(D1)),
MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(D1, SEQUENCE(LEN(D1)), 1))), x))))
```

For example:
[image]

Comment: This is what I wanted to do - Thanks! Here is your formula cleaned up a little: `=LET(s, A2, x, SEQUENCE(LEN(s)), LEFT(s, MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(s, x, 1))), x))))`.